# Python Threading with multiple functions and list

Tags: python, multithreading

My code is a much more complex version of the following.
I will try to explain what I want as clearly as possible.
consider I have the following code. few functions and list of numbers.

```
def main_fun(number):
    num = randint(1,10)
    sleep(num)
    return f"{num} --> {number}"


def fun_1(number):
    print(f"fun_1  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_2(number):
    print(f"fun_2  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_3(number):
    print(f"fun_3  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_4(number):
    print(f"fun_4  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_5(number):
    print(f"fun_5  :  {main_fun(number)}")


a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

You can see that there is a list with 11 numbers and 6 functions. main_fun() is the main function. I want to call the main_fun() through the other 5 functions using threading.

I want the script to work like this,
at first, the five functions will be called like this.(parallel using threading) i know how to do this. The next part is what tricky for me.

```
fun_1(1)
fun_2(2)
fun_3(3)
fun_4(4)
fun_5(5)
```

As you can see main_fun() will sleep for a radome amount of time before returning something.
so, say main_fun() called through fun_2() returned something first. meaning fun_2() finished running, then I want to pass the next number in the list (which is 6) and call fun_2() again(fun_2(6)).
And then, the function which finishes next need to be called with the next number in the list as an argument.
I hope i explained it clearly. I have been stuck with this for the past 2 days. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code where you're using threading? That might make your objective clearer

Comment: Check this https://pythonguides.com/python-threading-and-multithreading/

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. but not sure if it is the most efficient way. Here it is. I am sharing the entire code.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import threading

def main_fun(number):
    num = randint(1,10)
    sleep(num)
    return f"{num} --> {number}"


def fun_1(number):
    print(f"fun_1  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_2(number):
    print(f"fun_2  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_3(number):
    print(f"fun_3  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_4(number):
    print(f"fun_4  :  {main_fun(number)}")

def fun_5(number):
    print(f"fun_5  :  {main_fun(number)}")


a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


a_iter = iter(a)

thread_list = []

list_end = False

for fun in [fun_1,fun_2,fun_3,fun_4,fun_5]:
    try:
        num = next(a_iter)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fun,args=[num])
        thread_list.append([thread,fun])
        thread.start()
    except StopIteration:
        list_end = True
        break

while not list_end:
    try:
        for ind, [thread, fun] in enumerate(thread_list):
            thread: threading.Thread
            if not thread.is_alive():
                num = next(a_iter)
                thread_list[ind] = [threading.Thread(target=fun,args=[num]),fun]
                thread_list[ind][0].start()
    except StopIteration:
        list_end = True
```

Comment: If you execute (start) a number of threads and keep the thread references in a list, there's no reliable way to determine which of those threads finished first. Of course, you can tell *if* a thread has finished but not *when* it finished. Furthermore, if you start a large number of threads then write a loop that continuously examines those threads for is_alive() that could result in your main program utilising far more CPU than you would hope for. Finally, for CPU intensive activity you should consider concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.

Comment: @DarkKnight yes, i agree with your remark this code being not efficient enough. But for now, it does the work for me. getting stuck inside the infinite loop will utilize far more CPU as you mentioned. I couldn't find any other solution. I will update if i find any.